# Code golf as non-community wiki questions

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, code-golf

I know SO is a place for questions and answers, but I really like to challenge the community with my code-golf questions.

Up until now, they are all marked as community wiki, which means no one gets reputation over it, including the 'winning answer'.

Should I make my question 'normal' questions to let the 'winners' receive something back from participating?

Side note: I'd offer a bounty, but reputation is not unlimited.

**Edit**: How about user contributed bounties? a person who wants to 'see this problem solved' will donate a small amount of his/her reputation (10-20?) that will accumulate and be given when the answer is chosen. I know that will most likely be hard to add, but just throwing it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly add a bounty yourself, bounties are valid on cwiki questions. That would be my recommendation.

(also, you still get badges on cwiki questions, so there is that.)

As for pooling rep into bounties, that's in the planned tag already.

Comment: "bounties are valid on cwiki questions" -- they still cost, right?

Comment: free bounties, get outta here with your crazy talk!

Comment: I'll wait for the bounty pool feature...